# OpenGL: Looking for resource for understanding the use of the vertex transformation sequence

Tags: opengl, opengl-3

I'm looking into learning the basics of OpenGL only with v.3.0 methods onwards. I've reached the point of needing to use the equivalent of a "camera" [the basic goal is to 'look around with the mouse' in first person]. I [did ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498581/in-opengl-what-is-the-simplest-way-to-create-a-perspective-view-using-only-openg)  a specific question about it but it's probably further into what I should be learning (because I can't easily implement it). I have found several resources on the matter such as [this](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_transform.html) but they may not be ideal or they may be for OpenGL 1.x. methods

What I'm looking for is:

1. What do Matrices in OpenGL clearly represent? What do they represent in different contexts? (in relation to projection and final projection on the screen)
2. How can they be manipulated? What matrix should be manipulated to do what? When should it be manipulated? [Coding methods.]
3. Clear hints on communication of data. How to communicate data in relation to projection paths?

It seems to be an area extremely limited in Internet resources since most engines apparently either are already based on older engines that already do that (transformations / simply looking around with the mouse) or people that do use them are already specialists in areas related and expose little of their knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend this book : [Essential Mathematics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123742978)

If you can't afford it, which is comprehensible, then the openGL FAQ and Wiki are a good resource : http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/transformations.htm , especially 9.011 .

[edit] fixed link

Comment: It looks nice, thanks. The introductory passages I found seem to tackle exactly the problem I've encountered on the Internet: People are used to old engines and never learn that stuff and when Phones with 3D capabilities and Shaders come to being people started realizing they have to actually learn about it and there was a gap in knowledge resources available, at least in relation to modern APIs.

Comment: the link to essential mathematics links to the old edition. If you decide to buy it, make sure you take the blue one.